# Send button display is strange - workaround?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I specify the Facebook like/send buttons like so:

```
<fb:like href="[URL]" show_faces="false" width="428" action="recommend" font="tahoma" send="true"></fb:like>
```

In the process of displaying these buttons, they go through these three visual states:

1) Send button and Recommend button displayed side-by-side with Send button first.

2) Recommend button and Send button switches places, but the Send button displays below the expected display position.

3) Recommend button and Send button are displayed side-by-side normally, as the Send button has moved back up.

Is this an anomaly I can do something about by how I specify the button, or do I need to wait for a fix from Facebook?

***On edit, here's the code I'm using...***

After the body tag, I have (site-specific info redacted with angle brackets)...

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '<appid>',
      status: true,
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      channelUrl: '<siteroot>/channel.html',
      oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'facebook', 'like', href]);
    });
  };

  (function(d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
  }(document));
</script>
```

The button code is as follows:

```
<fb:like href="<pageurl>" show_faces="false" width="428" action="recommend" font="tahoma" send="true"></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this myself, but it sounds like something that could be caused by the fb:like tag being populated before the whole page is rendered.  How are you calling the javascript that initializes the tag?  You might try setting it up in the window.onload event so it doesn't get run until the page is fully loaded.

A few things to try:

Enclose the `<fb:like>` tag in a div styled with width:428px.

Change the async=true to async=false (temporarily just to see if it solves the problem).

Likewise, try chaning async=true to defer=true.

Change the code layout to this:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js' defer='defer'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '<appid>',
      status: true,
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      channelUrl: '<siteroot>/channel.html',
      oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'facebook', 'like', href]);
    });
  };
</script>
```

Or maybe even this:

```
<head>
window.onload=function() {
    d=document;
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(js);
  };
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: '<appid>',
      status: true,
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      channelUrl: '<siteroot>/channel.html',
      oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'facebook', 'like', href]);
    });
  };
</script>
```

Comment: I do the init just after the body tag, using the async script.  Wouldn't I have to use non-async script if calling from the onload?  Maybe I'm doing something non-standard, but I would like to use the async script in a way that works for everyone.

Comment: I mean the script that handles the fb:like tag...do you have a separate block for that?  The code that is "bundled" with the <fb:like> tag when you use the Facebook tool to generate it.

Comment: The code that is bundled with it is the init script, I thought.  I moved that to just following the body tag.

Comment: Just to be clear, I mean the code that starts with "<script>(function(d, s, id) {" and ends with "}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>".  If that executes just after the body tag, it may be trying to construct the fb:like button before the page is fully rendered.  Try it at the end of the page or even better, in an onload event.

Comment: I'm using the async version of that.  And funny enough, I wasn't using the latest code, so I just updated.  The problem I'm seeing is still there, however.

Comment: I added a few things worth trying to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the ideas.  Sadly, none of them changed the behavior.  Maybe I'll just write this off as an anomaly and hope the Facebook devs figure it out at some point.